# Solution for $y''=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following

$$
\begin{cases}
y''=0,\\
y(0)=y(2\pi))\\
y'(0)=y'(2\pi)
\end{cases}
$$

$$y''=0\rightarrow y'=a \rightarrow y=ax+b$$

using $y(0)=y(2\pi)$:

$$y(0)=b$$
and
$$y(2\pi)=2a\pi+b$$

So $$b=2a\pi+b\rightarrow a=0$$

We are left with $$y=b$$

Is it a trivial solution?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not stated as $y''=y$? If not then indeed the first condition gives you an affine function. The third is thus automatically satisfied and the second states that the function is horizontal, i.e. constant.

Comment: @b00nheT: you probably mean $y''+y=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right: $y’’+y=0$ would better fit the periodic boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Right. $y''=0$ describes a linear function and a linear function cannot take twice the same value unless the slope is zero.

By the way, $$y'(0)=y'(2\pi)$$ is implicit, $$y''=0\implies y'=C.$$

Comment: So $y\neq 0$ or $y=0$?

Comment: @newhere: why this alternative ?